# Azure AD B2C Claims do not include mapped Custom IdP claims

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have Azure AD B2C directory and have added our other separate Azure AD (AAD) as an Identity Provider (as Open ID Connect Provider) in Azure AD B2C. I am able to sign in just fine using the custom IdP which links to AAD.

I also have Identity provider claims mapping set as "User ID" to oid, "Display name" to name, "Given name" to given_name, "Surname" to family_name and "Email" to preferred_name (per following link). But when I get the token back and inspect it using https://jwt.ms/, it does not have those claims. When I  inspected the "idp_access_token" claim and it has oid, given_name, family_name etc. returned by AAD. I'm not sure where I'm missing. I want these claims to be in the token issued by B2C.

Any help is appreciated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow

I have selected all of these "Application Claims" in my user flow
[image]

Comment: In the user flow have you selected to return those claims under “Application Claims”?

Comment: Yes. I have updated the question with details.

Comment: Thanks @Vivek and Could you please follow document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-openid-connect

Comment: More Info... When I modify the Signup_Signin user flow to collect user attributes like Email Address, Given Name, then during user sign up, those values are prompted to by B2C to be collected from the user. In that case B2C token contains those claims but those values could be different from AAD store. I want those values to come from AAD store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably missed a step: [Configuring optional claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow#configuring-optional-claims).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm able to get the given name and surname claims now but still cannot get to the email. FYI..The email on the AAD side is also upn.

Comment: @VivekN No, it's not upn in AAD side. `idp_access_token` is access token. But the claim should be from the id token. I can confirm that `preferred_username` exists in the id token but it's wired that it doesn't return to the Azure B2C side. I set  "Email" to family_name but I still can't see a "email" claim (which includes family_name) in B2C id token. Not sure if it's a bug in built-in user flow here. I think it's another issue. Maybe you can open a new post for further discussion with more people. BTW, if my answer is helpful, you can mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. It is helpful. So, is it okay for us to decode 'idp_access_token' on the client app side and grab email from there? Is that a recommended practice?

Comment: @VivekN Not sure if it's a recommended practice but I think it should be feasible. Alternatively you can use user object id to query the user's email with Microsoft Graph.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as accepted answer as it puts me in the right direction. I will ask separate question for the email claim.